# Starting Notepad from command prompt causes notepad to complain about permissions

Tags: windows, command-line

When I start Notepad with no arguments using `notepad`, Notepad opens and works fine.

When I want it to create a new file and open it, using `notepad file.txt`, it opens as well, asks if it should create the file since it doesn't exist, proceeds to create it and then *not* open it and immediately display an alert that says *You don't have permission to open this file.*.

When I want to open an existing file, using `notepad actualFile.txt`, I get the same permission error alert.

I am starting Notepad by pressing Shift while right-clicking the right button to invoke context menu where *Open command window here* option becomes available. Same thing happens when I start command prompt using `Win+R` and entering `cmd`. It makes no difference whether I run Command Prompt as an administrator or not. The file permissions say *full control* for both my user and the Administrators group.

**I've tried the same thing at home, and it works fine, it only breaks on my work computer.** My work computer should be clean install without any special workplace setup, though, so I am not sure what could be the cause anyway.

Is there a way to compare process information for my home and work instances of the Command Prompt and explore the differences in permissions and owner contexts?

Comment: Try running cmd as administrator, does it happen then?

Comment: It makes no difference whether I run Notepad as an administrator or not.

Comment: Sorry, meant to say Command Prompt instead of notepad.

Comment: @TomášHübelbauer: Have you tried specifying a full path, e.g. `notepad c:\folder\test.txt`? It could be that the start directory has been altered somehow and you do not have write permissions for the relevant folder.

Comment: Can you please turn your comment to an answer, @James? The issue is that opening Comamnd Prompt from the context menu probably does 1) run cmd 2) cd to directory 3) clear console, so I am in context of system32, but the only line in Command Prompt says "C:\Users\Tomáš\Downloads\test", where I started it.

Comment: Please can you check the value of the following registry key in regedit: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\cmd\command`. This is what gets called when *Open command window here* is clicked and should change directory to the folder name passed as a parameter, I wonder if it has been changed for some reason.

Comment: It says `cmd.exe /s /k pushd "%V"`.

Comment: Which should be correct according to what I just googled. `pushd` is supposed to change the current directory to an argument which is `%V`, which should mean current directory when in context menu.

Comment: @TomášHübelbauer: Is there an `Autorun` value set under the key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor`?

Comment: There isn't one.